# Linked List with add and remove method

Tags: java, linked-list

Got an assignment to create a class that links elements together. 
Methods get(), add() and remove() were predefined by the assignment.

I actually managed to write code that creates such linked list,
but with the exception that the instance with value "Yo!" gets overwritten, when
adding new elements to the list and also I can't get the remove method working.
I really can't wrap my head around referencing object this way.
Could you help me correct my code ?

```
/**
 * 
 * Represents a linked list of elements.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
class LinkedElement<T> {
    /**
     * Adds a new linked element holding the given value at the end of the linked
     * elements.
     * 
     * @param newVal the new value.
     */
    public void add(T newVal) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Element(newVal);
        }

        Element next = new Element(newVal);
        Element current = head;

        if (current != null) {
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }

            current.setNext(next);
        }

        increaseListSize();

    }

    /**
     * Removes the i-th element from the linked elements. If {@code i == 0}, this
     * will effectively remove the head element. Thus, this method returns the
     * linked element that is the new head element.
     * 
     * @param i index of the element to remove.
     * @return the new head element.
     */
    public LinkedElement<T> remove(int i) {
        if (i < 1 || i > getListSize())
            return null;

        Element current = head;
        if (head != null) {
            for (int e = 0; e < i; i++) {
                if (current.getNext() == null)
                    return null;

                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());

            decreaseListSize();

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your get method: `Element current = head;` is correct.

There are several things that doesn't work in your remove method. This one should be working:

```
public void remove(int i) {
    if (i==0) {
        head = head.getNext();
        decreaseListSize();
        return;
    }

    if (i < 1 || i > getListSize()) {
        return;
    }

    Element current = head;
    if (head != null) {
        for (int e = 1; e < i; e++) {
            if (current.getNext() == null)
                return ;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
        decreaseListSize();
    }
}
```

Note that I changed return type to void since your method returned null in any case and return of head is no neccessary. If you want to return the head element you can easily adapt it and return head instead of nothing.
Furthermore, a note that the count - as so often in computer science - starts at 0. To remove the first element you have to write `headElement.remove(0);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `get` method is slightly wrong, you need to start `current` with `head` and not `head.next()`

```
   public T get(int i) {
    if (i < 0)
        return null;

    Element current = head;
    if (current != null) {
        for (int e = 0; e < i; e++) {
            if (current.getNext() == null)
                return null;

            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return current.getValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Oh didn't see that. Now it seams like the add()-method is already working fine. :)